# Factory classes

Tags: java, oop, object, factory

Personally I've never understood the idea of factory classes because it seems a whole lot more useful to just instantiate an Object directly. My question is simple, in what situation is the use of a factory class pattern the best option, for what reason, and what does a good factory class look like?

Comment: A factory method is most useful when you don't know precisely what class will be returned.  You may, eg, get a different class based on whether an accessed resource is local or remote.  Another case is where the the object being returned is a "composite".  For instance, I *wish* Java had some "gimme a file access" methods that would stick together the file and stream and buffer ad nauseum, rather than me having to put the stuff together.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The idea here is separation of concerns: If the code that uses the object also has enough information to instantiate it, you don't need a factory. However, if there is some logic or configuration involved that you don't want to have the API user to think about (or mess with), you can hide all that (and encapsulate it for reuse) in a factory.

Here is an example: You want to access one of the services provided by Google App Engine. The same code should work at both the development environment (of which there are two versions, master-slave and high-availabilty) and the completely different local development environment. Google does not want to tell you about the inner workings of their internal infrastructure, and you don't really want to know. So what they do is provide interfaces and factories (and several implementations of those interfaces for the factories to choose from that you don't even need to know about).

Answer (score 55):

Here is a real live factory from my code base. It's used to generated a sampler class that knows how to sample data from some dataset (it's originally in C#, so excuse any java faux-pas)

```
class SamplerFactory
{
  private static Hashtable<SamplingType, ISampler> samplers;

  static
  {
    samplers = new Hashtable<SamplingType, ISampler>();
    samplers.put(SamplingType.Scalar, new ScalarSampler());
    samplers.put(SamplingType.Vector, new VectorSampler());
    samplers.put(SamplingType.Array, new ArraySampler());
  }

  public static ISampler GetSampler(SamplingType samplingType)
  {
    if (!samplers.containsKey(samplingType))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sampling type or sampler not initialized");
    return samplers.get(samplingType);
  }
}
```

and here is an example usage:

```
ISampler sampler = SamplerFactory.GetSampler(SamplingType.Array);
dataSet = sampler.Sample(dataSet);
```

As you see, it's not much code, and it might even be shorter and faster just to do

```
ArraySampler sampler = new ArraySampler();
dataSet = sampler.Sample(dataSet);
```

than to use the factory. So why do I even bother? Well, there are two basic reasons, that build on each other:

1. First, it is the simplicity and maintainability of the code. Let's say that in the calling code, the `enum` is provided as a parameter. I.e. if I had a method that need to process the data, including sampling, I can write:

   ```
   void ProcessData(Object dataSet, SamplingType sampling)
   {
     //do something with data
     ISampler sampler = SamplerFactory.GetSampler(sampling);
     dataSet= sampler.Sample(dataSet);
     //do something other with data
   }
   ```

   instead of a more cumbersome construct, like this:

   ```
   void ProcessData(Object dataSet, SamplingType sampling)
   {
     //do something with data
     ISampler sampler;
     switch (sampling) {
       case SamplingType.Scalar:  
         sampler= new ScalarSampler();
         break;
       case SamplingType.Vector:  
         sampler= new VectorSampler();
         break;
       case SamplingType.Array:
         sampler= new ArraySampler();
         break;
       default:
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sampling type");
     }
     dataSet= sampler.Sample(dataSet);
     //do something other with data
   }
   ```

   Note that this monstrosity should be written each and every time I need me some sampling. And you can imagine how fun it will be to change if, let's say, I added a parameter to `ScalarSampler` constructor, or added a new `SamplingType`. And this factory has only three options now, imagine a factory with 20 implementations.
2. Second, it's the decoupling of the code. When I use a factory, the calling code does not know or need to know that a class called `ArraySampler` even exists. The class could even be resolved at run-time, and the call site would be none the wiser. So, consequently, I am free to change the `ArraySampler` class as much as I want, including, but not limited to, deleting the class outright, if, e.g. I decide that the `ScalarSampler` should be used for array data as well. I would just need to change the line

   ```
   samplers.put(SamplingType.Array, new ArraySampler());
   ```

   to

   ```
   samplers.put(SamplingType.Array, new ScalarSampler());
   ```

   and it would work magically. I do not have to change a single line of code in the calling classes, which could number in the hundreds. Effectively, the factory makes me in control of what and how the sampling occurs, and any sampling changes are efficiently encapsulated within a single factory class that is interfaced with the rest of the system.

Comment: +1 thanks for the real example. It would be really helpful in understanding from the "non-book" example.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use the factory pattern when the implementation of an interface is unknown at run time or it can be made dynamic.

This means that as a developer, I work against a known interface to the instance of the object, but I'm not concerned with how the implementation works.

Take, for example.  You could use a factory pattern to provide you with objects from a database.  You don't care if that database is a flat file, local/single user database, server database or web resource, only that the factory can generate and manage those objects.

I'd hate to have to write implementations for each of those cases :P

Comment: Isn't your Take-example more like the builder pattern?

Comment: @DanielK factory and builder are similar, where builder takes properties and configures the object, factory generally returns a object which implements a given interface

Answer (score 4):

From Effective Java book by Joshua Bloch, partially rewritten by me:

1) Static factory methods (**SFM**), unlike constructors, have names.

```
public static ComplexNumber one () {
    return new ComplexNumber(1, 0);
}

public static ComplexNumber imgOne () {
    return new ComplexNumber(0, 1);
}

public static ComplexNumber zero () {
    return new ComplexNumber(0, 0);
}
```

2) It is not required to create a new object each time `SFM` is/are invoked

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE; 
}
```

3) `SFM` can return an object of any subtype of their return type.

4) `SFM` reduce the verbosity of creating parameterized type instances.

```
public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newInstance() {
    return new HashMap<K, V>();
}

Map<String, List<String>> m = HashMap.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement Thilo's answer, let us suppose that you have an object which only has a boolean as a constructor: it would be a total waste to build one each time, since it only has two possible values.

In this case, you can create static factory methods. Java's `Boolean` class is an example: `Boolean.valueOf()`.

Comment: That is more of a "multiton"/flyweight pattern example, though.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), but basic idea of most design patterns is to introduce some abstraction to achieve better maintainability and/or reusability. Factory method pattern is no exception, what it does is to abstract away the complexity of creation from the code.

For simple case it seems unnecessary to use factory pattern, a simply `new` is enough. But when you need more flexibility or functionality, this pattern may help.

For example, unless a new instance is required, the static factory `valueOf(boolean)` is generally a better choice than `new Bealean(boolean)`, for it avoids creating unnecessary objects. Factory method pattern is also known as **Virtual Constructor**. As we know, polymorphism is one of the key features of OOP, but constructor cannot be polymorphic, this shortcoming can be overcome by factory method pattern.

In essence, instantiating an object directly(typically via `new`) is barely a concrete *implementation*, while factory method pattern shields a *volatile* **implementation** by a *stable* **interface**(not limited to the `interface` in Java), pushing the logic of object-creating behind some abstraction to ensure more maintainable and reusable code.

As a final word, to fully understand the benefit of factory method pattern and other design patterns, one need grasp the essence of OOP, including [data abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Data_abstraction), polymorphic abstraction and [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle.

Answer (score 0):

Factory by itself does not show its beauty so easily. Is when you combine it with other patterns when you see the real benefits for example, if you want to use the decorator pattern, instantiating an object directly may add some additional coupling to your code. As the OOP teacher says, coupling is bad :) so if you were to instantiate the decorated object and didn't want to increase coupling then you could use a factory.